# Determining chi squared from a random variable histogram on Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, chi-squared

I'm trying to obtain a chi-squared value for my code, which is graphing a histogram of random variables on python. 
Although, it is giving me strange outputs for the statistic.
Unsure what I'm doing wrong.

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np
 from scipy.stats import chisquare

 xv=[]

 for i in range(1,1001):
      s = np.random.uniform(-1,1,6)
      np.all(s >= -1)
      True
      np.all(s < 1)
      True
      temp = np.sum(s)

      xv.append(temp)


count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(xv, 100, normed=True)
plt.show()

print(chisquare(xv))
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'Although, it is giving me strange outputs for the statistic. ' What is the output? And what is `True` in your cycle code?